# Can't estimate gas usage in Mist 0.5.2

Tags: mist, wallets, gas, gas-estimate

Since I upgraded to Mist 0.5.2, I get this when trying to transfer funds:

> We can't estimate your gas usage properly, as you need at least 1 ether in your account

My account has 3 ethers.

Comment: 3 digit in Ether or Wei?

Comment: Ether. xxx.xxxx...

Comment: Tried to send xtran. Looked like it was hanging on "sending" , choose to exit the wallet and got timeout message on send_transaction function

Comment: Ran geth ... hanging on "I0314 15:54:41.582268    6574 downloader.go:288] Block synchronisation started" . This may be the root cause of the problem. pm2 list is empty.

Comment: Wallet block count 15 mins , thus many blocks out of sync with geth eth.blocknumber and https://ethstats.net best block

Comment: Kicked into life after Homestead , even got a Unicorn msg , 20hrs after the strain

Answer (score 5):

The wallet block count always lagged behind the eth.blocknumber as reported by Geth and ethstats. After upgrading to Homestead, this problem disappeared.

Comment: You can mark this question as answered, so people know you've solved it